# How to unlock characters and stages in Super Smash Land?

Tags: super-smash-land

[Super Smash Land](http://www.supersmashland.com/) is a demake of Super Smash Bros, written in Game Maker 8 and with a retro Game Boy feel.

It starts with 4 available characters (Mario, Kirby, Link, Pikachu), half of the available stages in versus mode.

I know that finishing once the arcade mode will unlock the Mega Man stage. But what must I do to unlock the other stages? And how to unlock the characters? And the Endless mode (currently grayed-out in the main menu)?

Comment: I don't know about unlocking stages, but [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DT47IPafXMI) (be sure to expand its description) shows how to unlock what appears to be the only character you haven't unlocked yet - Vaporeon. The video actually shows Endless Mode getting unlocked as well, but doesn't bother making the prerequisites clear.

Comment: Actually, I've only unlocked the Mega Man stage, not the character.

Comment: Ah, I somehow managed to ignore the word "Stage" after "Mega Man".

Answer (score 4):

Megaman is unlocked after beating Arcade as all 4 starting characters.

Vaporeon appears randomly on the Saffron City stage, defeat her when she shows during versus, then finish the match to unlock her. A method to get this to work was shown in a youtube video in which you could start a versus match with 99 lives, let idle for a while before Vaporeon shows, then after defeating her you can suicide your remaining lives to end the match.

Comment: suicide 99 lives? couldn't you just have 5 or so and idle away from the hazards, say, on the floating platforms until Vaporeon comes?

Answer (score 2):

You get endless mode when you have all people. It's kinda like all-star mode in brawl/melee

Answer (score 1):

Endless Mode is unlocked when you have both Mega Man and Vaporeon.

Answer (score 0):

To unlock everything go to the file "SSL-D3" and edit it so all the "d" read as "e"!

Comment: This seems more of a cheat rather than an actual answer.

Comment: It's not a cheat it's a SAVE FILE EDIT! Hint is in my name!

Comment: Save file edits are cheats...